# How to press the button sound worked twice click

Tags: android, button, audio

I want to make button sound, on the beginning, I just input `start()` but I read, I must add `reset()` and `release()`. but when I click twice the button, the app has been error "Unfortunately, the App has stopped." .

here my code

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ka);
ImageButton ka = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ka);
            ka.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
```

That button inside the `AlertDialog`

from Android Monitor :

[here from my Android Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAaXP.png)

Comment: Post error log here.

Comment: Are you supposed to release onCompletion? sounds like could be the problem. What happens if you comment out the `mp.reset()` + `mp.release()`

Comment: it work, but i need to release that sound from memory after start

Comment: and still have "E/MediaPlayer: Error (-19,0)"